# Communicate through xmpp protocol for php and ios

Tags: php, ios, xmpp

I am a php developer and I installed xampp in my machine. I have a mysql database where user table is there. This table is containing userid, name and online status(1 or 0).

I have to send the list of current online users to ios client, which is not supposed to request again and again. Instead of that if any changes occurs in table, automatically it will update in ios. I need only online user list, not for the te

By googling, I come to know that we can use XMPP protocol for that. But as I am using xampp server, it is using http protocol. So could you please let me know whether my googling is correct or not. If yes then please guide me how to proceed according to above mentioned environment and if no then please suggest what will be the better solution for that.

Comment: since there will be alot communication between the host and devices (everytime online status changed) you will have a lot communication. Maybe you should try socket connections?

Comment: If you want to use the xmpp protocol instead of http then you must use a xmpp server, not a http server.

Comment: to install xmpp server, what to do? whether I have to uninstall xampp server or it is different?

Comment: xampp != xmpp...as @arkascha said, you will need an XMPP server to support XMPP clients.